# convert factor to numeric shows coercion after using gsub

Tags: r

The numbers the I have just don't add up correctly compared to excel and it is still showing `NAs introduced by coercion` after removing the commas and converting it to numeric. The numbers are way less than what it is in excel.

`data$bigNumber <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",data$bigNumber ))`

where

`data$bigNumber <- c("552","513","1,512","1296","1,683","2,172","314","690","923","1,870","602","583","456","760","88","504","477","317","1,453","1,527")`

Btw this is uploaded via a csv file if that matters

Comment: Your code works for me. I don't get any coercion warnings and the results of `sum` match excel. Can you make it reproducible?

Comment: I'm importing this from a large excel file. I am not sure if there is funky numbers that's not visible in there that makes it off, although I do not see anything weird when looking at the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at what is causing the error, probably some "funky numbers" in the data, as you say. You can do this by running the conversion, and then looking back at which values produced NA results. You should see clearly then what's causing the problem.

Here's your example dataset, with an intentional "funky number" thrown in.

```
data <- data.frame( bigNumber = c("552","513","1,512","12-96","1,683","2,172","314","690","923","1,870","602","583","456","760","88","504","477","317","1,453","1,527") )
```

Now we can create a vector in the same way as you've done, but without replacing the one we have on input:

```
bigNumTest <- as.numeric( gsub( ",", "", data$bigNumber ) )
```

Now, since there were NAs introduced, we can look at which values produced them.

```
data[ is.na( bigNumTest ), "bigNumber" ]
```

In this case, the output here is `[1] "12-96"`, so we can see clearly that there's a hyphen causing the issue. We can fix that one issue or, if there's a common issue amongst the data (eg: lots of hyphens thrown in randomly where they shouldn't be), we can run an extra clarifying step to make sure the common issue is resolved before the numeric conversion (in this case it can be built into your existing `gsub` step):

```
data$bigNumber <- as.numeric( gsub( ",|-", "", data$bigNumber ) )
```

-

-

-

NOTE: since you're doing a `gsub` conversion on your factor column before converting to numeric, you're coercing a character vector from the factors you had to begin with (based on your question title). As long as you're aware that this is a necessary step you're OK, but for anyone having trouble converting factors to numeric, please heed the warning in `?factor`:

> Warning
>
> The interpretation of a factor depends on both the codes and the "levels" attribute. Be careful only to compare factors with the same set of levels (in the same order). In particular, as.numeric applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

Comment: Thank you. This is was a great way to test to see what was going on, however, I see that it returns `null` I am at lost as to which numbers are correct now (excel vs r)